# Strange behavior extracting function arguments values in R

Tags: r, evaluation

How can I extract all function arguments values in a list?

I tried this:

```
x <- 1; y <- 2; z <- 3
testFunc <- function(a, b, c){
  args <- as.list(sys.call())[-1]
  evaluatedArgs <- lapply(args, function(x) eval(x))
  evaluatedArgs
}
str(testFunc(x,y,z))
```

> List of 3
>   $ : symbol x
>   $ : num 2
>   $ : num 3

As you can see, there is a strange conflict if with `x` inside `function(x)` and the outside variable `x`, that prevents the evaluation of the first parameter.

How can this conflict be solved? For me it's a strange mix of scope.

***Update***
Now I know `lapply(args, function(x) eval(x))` solve the problem, but I would like to understand the why the conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `args` variable is a "list" of "symbol"s and are passed as arguments in your anonymous `lapply` function. So, isolating the issue, you're essentially doing:

```
x = 10; y = 20
(function(x) eval(x))(substitute(x))
#x
(function(x) eval(x))(substitute(y))
#[1] 20
```

`eval` evaluates its argument in its `parent.frame` which, here, is the `environment()` of the above function. That environment, contains the argument(s) of the function and the passed values:

```
(function(x) as.list(environment()))(substitute(x))
#$x
#x
#
(function(x) as.list(environment()))(substitute(y))
#$x
#y
```

In the first case, `eval` needs to evaluate the *argument* "x" which translates to evaluate the *symbol* "x". To evaluate the *symbol* "x", it, first, needs to find it and it finds it in its own environment as it is its argument. The "x" that is found contains the *symbol* "x" and that is returned. In the second case, evaluating the *argument* "x" translates to evaluate the *symbol* "y", which is not in its environment, but found in its parent environments where it contains the value "20" and that is returned.

To be specific we need to pass an evaluation environment to `eval`:

```
(function(x) { e = environment(); eval(x, parent.env(e)) })(substitute(x))
#[1] 10
(function(x) { e = environment(); eval(x, parent.env(e)) })(substitute(y))
#[1] 20
```

Here, the argument is evaluated to the parent environment of the function's current environment (i.e. -in this case- the `.GlobalEnv`). So, modifying your function to search correctly:

```
x = 1; y = 2; z = 3
testFunc = function(a, b, c)
{
    args = as.list(sys.call())[-1]
    e = environment()
    lapply(args, function(x) eval(x, e))
}
```

we get:

```
str(testFunc(x,y,z))
#List of 3
# $ : num 1
# $ : num 2
# $ : num 3
```